# Sagetex: problems with layout, and sage results

Tags: sagetex

I am writing an article with some embedded Sage code, using Sagetex for the purpose.  Mostly it works well, with multiple uses of the `sageexample` environment.  However, there are several things I'd like to be able to do:

1. Decrease the space between the sage commands
2. Have the "sage" keyword typeset in a different color (like in the `sagecommandline` environment)
3. Alternatively, typeset the `sagecommandline` environment without line numbers.

The documentation, while probably complete, doesn't describe easy ways to do such things.

I also have the occasional Sage output which is different from when I run Sage in a notebook.  Usually I check that the Sage commands give the result I want, then I put all the commands inside a `sageexample` environment and run latex-sage-latex on my file.  But I'm finding sometimes the output typeset in my latex file is very different from what I see in the notebook.  This is particularly noticeable with the various `simplify` commands.  I can't seem to create a MWE, so I'm wondering if this is a known general problem, for which there's an easy fix?

Comment: Without an MWE, we can't help you on the last topic. And for the first three topics it would be nice to see a little example in order to see if the space between the environments is set correctly or not. Point 2: Maybe use `listings` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Locate the relevant bits in sagetex.sty. Then you have several options:

- place a modified copy of sagetex.sty near your document,
- in the latex preamble of your document, change the relevant bits
  using \makeatletter and \makeatother if necessary,
- create an extra sty file with such changes,
  and \usepackage it after \usepackage{sagetex}.

Answer (score 0):

Those are really issues with the `listings` package and you should be able to deal with them reasonably without editing `sagetex.sty` or anything like that; see the `example.tex` file included in Sage which has an example of changing some of the colors.

For the line numbers, you'll need to consult the `listings` documentation and see how one turns the line numbers off.